# Multi-threaded merge sort doesn't sort the array correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, mergesort

The following code is supposed to merge sort an array using multiple threads. The idea is to split the array into approximate same-size sub arrays and sort them concurrently using threads. Then, after they are all sorted (after the `for` loop of `pthread_join`), they are merged together. However, my code right not doesn't sort the array correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Arguments
{
    long *nums;
    int start;
    int end;
    long *result;
} SortThreadArgs;

/** The number of threads to be used for sorting. Default: 1 */
int thread_count = 2;
pthread_mutex_t merge_lock;

/**
 * Print the given array of longs, an element per line.
 */
void print_long_array(const long *array, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%ld\n", array[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Merge two slices of nums into the corresponding portion of target.
 */
void merge(long nums[], int from, int mid, int to, long target[])
{
    int left = from;
    int right = mid;

    // acquire lock before accessing shared data
    pthread_mutex_lock(&merge_lock);

    int i = from;
    for (; i < to && left < mid && right < to; i++)
    {
        if (nums[left] <= nums[right])
        {
            target[i] = nums[left];
            left++;
        }
        else
        {
            target[i] = nums[right];
            right++;
        }
    }
    if (left < mid)
    {
        memmove(&target[i], &nums[left], (mid - left) * sizeof(long));
    }
    else if (right < to)
    {
        memmove(&target[i], &nums[right], (to - right) * sizeof(long));
    }

    // release lock after modifying shared data
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&merge_lock);
}

/**
 * Sort the given slice of nums into target.
 *
 * Warning: nums gets overwritten.
 */
void merge_sort_aux(long nums[], int from, int to, long target[])
{
    if (to - from <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (from + to) / 2;
    merge_sort_aux(target, from, mid, nums);
    merge_sort_aux(target, mid, to, nums);
    merge(nums, from, mid, to, target);
}

void *sort_thread(void *arg)
{
    SortThreadArgs *args = (SortThreadArgs *)arg;
    long *nums = args->nums;
    int start = args->start;
    int end = args->end;
    long *result = args->result;

    merge_sort_aux(nums, start, end, result);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Sort the given array and return the sorted version.
 *
 * The result is malloc'd so it is the caller's responsibility to free it.
 *
 * Warning: The source array gets overwritten.
 */
long *merge_sort(long nums[], int count)
{
    // Check if thread_count is divisible by count
    int mod = count % thread_count;

    // Create a temp array that has the same elements as the given array
    long *result = calloc(count, sizeof(long));
    assert(result != NULL);
    memmove(result, nums, count * sizeof(long));

    pthread_mutex_init(&merge_lock, NULL);

    pthread_t threads[thread_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        // Calculate the start and end index based on the thread_num
        // i.e. Splitting the array into approximately same-size sub arrays
        int start = i * (count / thread_count);
        int end;
        if (i == thread_count - 1 && mod != 0) {
            end = count;
        } else {
            end = (i + 1) * (count / thread_count);
        }
        SortThreadArgs args = {nums, start, end, result};
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort_thread, &args);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // perform final merge operation on all subarrays
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        int start = i * (count / thread_count);
        int mid = start;
        int end;
        if (i == thread_count - 1 && mod != 0) {
            end = count;
        } else {
            end = (i + 1) * (count / thread_count);
        }
        merge(nums, 0, mid, end, result);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&merge_lock);

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int count = 10;
    long array[10] = { 4, 8, 3, 10, 6, 7, 5, 1, 9, 2 };
    long *result = merge_sort(array, count);
    print_long_array(result, count);
}
```

The way I split the array into sub arrays is in the first loop in `merge_sort` function. Based on the counter `i`, I calculate the `start` and `end` index. For example, if `thread_count = 2` and `count = 10`, for i = 0, start = 0, end = 5; for i = 1, start = 5, end = 10.

In the array `{4, 8, 3, 10, 6, 7, 5, 1, 9, 2}`, the printed output is:

```
1
2
2
4
5
8
3
9
10
6
```

This is really strange because there's a repeated 2. Hypothetically my idea should work correctly, but I really don't know what's the underlying bug that caused this. Any help is appreciated!

When I tried to print each sub array in the for loop after `pthread_join`, it shows that the sub arrays are not even sorted.

---

**Update**

The following code now works correctly for single-threaded merge sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <assert.h>

/** The number of threads to be used for sorting. Default: 1 */
int thread_count = 1;

typedef struct Arguments
{
    long *nums;
    int from;
    int to;
    long *target;
} merge_sort_args;

/**
 * Print the given array of longs, an element per line.
 */
void print_long_array(const long *array, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%ld\n", array[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Merge two slices of nums into the corresponding portion of target.
 */
void merge(long nums[], int from, int mid, int to, long target[])
{
    int left = from;
    int right = mid;

    int i = from;
    for (; i < to && left < mid && right < to; i++)
    {
        if (nums[left] <= nums[right])
        {
            target[i] = nums[left];
            left++;
        }
        else
        {
            target[i] = nums[right];
            right++;
        }
    }
    if (left < mid)
    {
        memcpy(&target[i], &nums[left], (mid - left) * sizeof(long));
    }
    else if (right < to)
    {
        memcpy(&target[i], &nums[right], (to - right) * sizeof(long));
    }
}

/**
 * Sort the given slice of nums into target.
 *
 * Warning: nums gets overwritten.
 */
void merge_sort_aux(long nums[], int from, int to, long target[])
{
    if (to - from <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (from + to) / 2;
    merge_sort_aux(target, from, mid, nums);
    merge_sort_aux(target, mid, to, nums);
    merge(nums, from, mid, to, target);
}

void *sort_thread(void *arg) {
    merge_sort_args *msa = (merge_sort_args *)arg;

    merge_sort_aux(msa->nums, msa->from, msa->to, msa->target);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Sort the given array and return the sorted version.
 *
 * The result is malloc'd so it is the caller's responsibility to free it.
 *
 * Warning: The source array gets overwritten.
 */
long *merge_sort(long nums[], int count)
{
    long *result = calloc(count, sizeof(long));
    assert(result != NULL);

    memcpy(result, nums, count * sizeof(long));

    pthread_t threads[thread_count];
    merge_sort_args args[thread_count];
    // Split the array into sub arrays here
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        int start = i * (count / thread_count);
        int end = (i + 1) * (count / thread_count);
        args[i] = (merge_sort_args) {nums, start, end, result};
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort_thread, &args[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        int start = i * (count / thread_count);
        int mid = start;
        int end = (i + 1) * (count / thread_count);
        merge(nums, 0, mid, end, result);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    long array[10] = { 10, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 9, 3, 6 };
    int count = 10;
    long *result = merge_sort(array, count);
    print_long_array(result, count);
}
```

Comment: Side note: `memcpy` is generally more efficient than `memmove`. The latter function should therefore only be used if it is possible that both memory regions overlap.

Comment: Side note: I don't see the need for the mutex, because all threads write to different parts of the array. If the function `merge` acquires a mutex every time before doing any work, you effectively make the program single-threaded, which defeats the whole purpose of using threads.

Comment: `SortThreadArgs args = {nums, start, end, result};` is an automatic variable on the stack, which becomes undefined when the surrounding `for` loop exits. This will invoke Undefined Behaviour. Each thread needs its own `SortThreadArgs` which lasts at least as long as the thread is running.

Comment: @pmacfarlane does it mean I should use something like malloc for `args`?

Comment: You can just declare it as `SortThreadArgs args[thread_count];` Then set each array member appropriately and pass the address of each to their thread. Fixing that makes me at least get the initial split working now, but the sort still doesn't work.

Comment: @eternal-sphere: Yes, `malloc` would also work, but I would recommend a local array as recommended in the previous comment by someone else. However, you must make sure that this array does not go out of scope before the call to `pthread_join`, because otherwise, the pointers passed to the threads may become invalid.

Comment: @pmacfarlane How did you initialize them? Did you do `args[i] = (merge_sort_args*) {nums, start, end, result};`?

Comment: I initialised the fields separately. There are only four of them. `args[i].nums = nums;` etc.

Comment: @pmacfarlane could you post the code that you have changed so far?

Comment: @pmacfarlane After initialization, did you do `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort_thread, &args[i]);`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel This works!! Let me update the question with what I have so far

Comment: @eternal-sphere: I deleted my last comment, because there was something strange about it. For some reason, the `pthread_create` call was calling `merge_sort_aux` instead of `sort_thread`. I guess I got confused with all the different revisions of the code, or maybe it was a change that I made during experimentation.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah sorry about the different revisions of the code. Could you check if my updated code works on yours?

Comment: @eternal-sphere: Yes, that looks good now. You no longer have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). `args[i]` will not go out ot scope before the call to `pthread_join`. This means that `args[i]` is guaranteed to exist for the entire lifetime of the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you compute the slice boundaries only works if the array length is a multiple of the number of threads.  You should instead use this:

```
long *merge_sort(long nums[], int count)
{
    long *result = calloc(count, sizeof(long));
    assert(result != NULL);

    memcpy(result, nums, count * sizeof(long));

    pthread_t threads[thread_count];
    merge_sort_args args[thread_count];
    // Split the array into sub arrays here
    for (long long i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        int start = (i * count) / thread_count;
        int end = ((i + 1) * count) / thread_count;
        args[i] = (merge_sort_args) { nums, start, end, result };
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort_thread, &args[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < thread_count; i++) {
        int mid = args[i].from;
        int end = args[i].to;
        merge(nums, 0, mid, end, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

There is another major problem: you do not handle the source and destination arrays correctly in the `mergesort_aux` and `merge` functions. As the source array is modified anyway, you should just sort and merge in place using the last argument as temporary working space.

Here is a modified version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

/** The number of threads to be used for sorting. Default: 1 */
int thread_count = 3;

typedef struct Arguments {
    long *nums;
    int from;
    int to;
    long *temp;
} merge_sort_args;

/**
 * Print the given array of longs, an element per line.
 */
void print_long_array(const long *array, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%ld\n", array[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Merge two slices of nums using the temp work space
 */
void merge(long nums[], int from, int mid, int to, long temp[])
{
    int i = from;
    int left = from;
    int right = mid;

    memcpy(&temp[from], &nums[from], sizeof(*nums) * (to - from));

    for (i = left = from, right = mid; left < mid && right < to; i++) {
        if (temp[left] <= temp[right]) {
            nums[i] = temp[left++];
        } else {
            nums[i] = temp[right++];
        }
    }
    if (left < mid) {
        memcpy(&nums[i], &temp[left], (mid - left) * sizeof(*nums));
    } else {
        memcpy(&nums[i], &temp[right], (to - right) * sizeof(*nums));
    }
}

/**
 * Sort the given slice of nums.
 */
void merge_sort_aux(long nums[], int from, int to, long temp[])
{
    if (to - from > 1) {
        int mid = from + (to - from) / 2;
        merge_sort_aux(nums, from, mid, nums);
        merge_sort_aux(nums, mid, to, temp);
        merge(nums, from, mid, to, temp);
    }
}

void *sort_thread(void *arg) {
    merge_sort_args *msa = (merge_sort_args *)arg;

    merge_sort_aux(msa->nums, msa->from, msa->to, msa->temp);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Sort the given array in place.
 */
void merge_sort(long nums[], int count)
{
    long *temp = calloc(count, sizeof(long));
    assert(temp != NULL);

    pthread_t threads[thread_count];
    merge_sort_args args[thread_count];
    // Split the array into sub arrays here
    for (long long i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        int start = (i * count) / thread_count;
        int end = ((i + 1) * count) / thread_count;
        args[i] = (merge_sort_args) { nums, start, end, temp };
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sort_thread, &args[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < thread_count; i++) {
        int mid = args[i].from;
        int end = args[i].to;
        merge(nums, 0, mid, end, temp);
    }
    free(temp);
}

int main(void)
{
    long array[10] = { 10, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 9, 3, 6 };
    int count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    merge_sort(array, count);
    print_long_array(array, count);
}
```